# Terraform loop over two lists

Tags: terraform

I need to create 8 aws routes using the following parameters.

```
route_table_id   = module.vpc.private_route_table_ids (4 rtb ids)
destination_cidr = ["1.1.0.0/16", "1.2.0.0/16"]
```

How can I do it declining this resource once?

```
resource "aws_route" "r" {
  route_table_id              = rtb_id
  destination_ipv6_cidr_block = cidrs
  egress_only_gateway_id      = aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.egress.id
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct)?

Comment: I think it would help if you can elaborate on how exactly you want to combine those. For example, perhaps you could show an example of what it would look like if you manually wrote out all of the resource declarations, which will then allow readers to see the systematic pattern you're trying to create and suggest ways to write it using Terraform expressions intead.